# Not able to open a Mac OS Extended (Journaled) SSD disk in Boot Camp

Tags: bootcamp, hfs+

I have installed the full version of Paragon's HFS+. I am fully able to read/write files from the partition that boots OS X, but not an external SSD with the same format.

I get the "pling" sound when I connect it, and I find it in Disk Management (though the format of the disk is not recognized). When following the Help from HFS+, I am not able to complete Step 2:

> Call the popup menu for a HFS+/HFSX volume (right click of the
>   mouse button), then select Change Drive Letter and Paths…

The "Change Drive Letter and Paths" option is grey and unclickable. The only thing I can click on is "Delete volume" or "Help".

Does anyone know what I can do to access the external SSD from Boot Camp?

diskutil cs list:

```
CoreStorage logical volume groups (1 found)
|
+-- Logical Volume Group 4B2BB594-30B4-44EF-B948-B6CFCF9C306F
    =========================================================
    Name:         Macintosh HD
    Status:       Online
    Size:         120473067520 B (120.5 GB)
    Free Space:   12652544 B (12.7 MB)
    |
    +-< Physical Volume 3DE0D8BA-2D65-4BDC-873E-8DB03D9D89E6
    |   ----------------------------------------------------
    |   Index:    0
    |   Disk:     disk1s2
    |   Status:   Online
    |   Size:     120473067520 B (120.5 GB)
    |
    +-> Logical Volume Family 86D3701B-9522-409A-BFE1-BD65C802DEAB
        ----------------------------------------------------------
        Encryption Status:       Unlocked
        Encryption Type:         None
        Conversion Status:       NoConversion
        Conversion Direction:    -none-
        Has Encrypted Extents:   No
        Fully Secure:            No
        Passphrase Required:     No
        |
        +-> Logical Volume C0ECB057-CE38-4C8C-B69A-14898070383E
            ---------------------------------------------------
            Disk:                  disk2
            Status:                Online
            Size (Total):          120108089344 B (120.1 GB)
            Conversion Progress:   -none-
            Revertible:            No
            LV Name:               External SSD
            Volume Name:           External SSD
            Content Hint:          Apple_HFS
```

Below you see a screenshot of the Disk Management window (unfortunately in Norwegian)

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Disk 1 looks like a typical, bootable OS X drive with an EFI-partition (200 MiB), a main OS X volume and a Recovery HD partition (620 MiB).

I can't say it for sure, but I'd assume your external SSD (disk1 in the Disk Management screenshot) contains a CoreStorage Logical Volume Group on the second partition (112.20 GiB).

To check if the second partition of your external disk contains a CoreStorage LVG boot to an OS X volume and enter `diskutil list` or `diskutil cs list`. If you detect the volume type Apple_CoreStorage next to the second partition of your external drive after entering the first command or a CoreStorage Logical Volume Group or a Logical Volume with the size of ~120 GB after entering the second command, your external disk contains a CoreStorage volume.

A Paragon [knowledge base article](http://kb_wp.paragon-software.com/article/70) states that Paragon HFS+ isn't compatible with CoreStorage:

> ...
>
> [HFS+ for Windows]
>
> If you are running HFS+ for Windows in a Bootcamp configuration, you won’t be able to see Mac OS X partition due to Core Storage restrictions. If you can disable Core Storage as described above, this will give you access to Mac OS X system drive from Bootcamp.

To enable r/w support you have to revert the CoreStorage LVG to a normal HFS+ volume.

To revert a CoreStorage volume boot to a Recovery HD or the OS X volume on your internal disk. Enter `diskutil cs list` and copy the Logical Volume UUID. Then enter: `diskutil cs revert LVUUID`. ***Some CoreStorage LVs aren't revertible***. If you have enabled FileVault on the external main volume you have to use a passphrase: `diskutil cs revert LVUUID -passphrase [passphrase]`.

Comment: Ah, thank you. I may be dumb, but how do I revert from CoreStorage to normal HFS+?

Comment: @Goat'sMilk revert how-to - added

Comment: When I run in Terminal "diskutil list", it says that the external ssd's type is "Apple_HFS".

Comment: @Goat'sMilk what does `diskutil cs list` say?

Comment: See edited question.

Comment: I was able to convert the CoreStorage disk to HFS+, and it is all good now.